# Get button from view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to return a button object from a view to subsequently run `setText` against.
I am having trouble converting it though.
Any advice appreciated.

```
public Button aiPlayerPick() {
        Button btn = null;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button && view.getTag() == aiPickedButton) {

                        View btn_v = view.findViewWithTag(aiPickedButton);
                        System.out.println("Button: " + btn_v);
                        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_v); // Problem is here, I can't get that view to be seen as a button

                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return btn;
    }
```

Comment: Tried that but it still has more or less the same problem.
`btn_v` not being recognised

Comment: btn = (Button) view.findViewWithTag(aiPickedButton); Just use that you already have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already retrieved the `View` (parent of the `Button`) to your code with:

```
View btn_v = view.findViewWithTag(aiPickedButton);
```

So the only thing you need to do is cast it to be a `Button` with `btn = (Button) someView`. Your code would look like:

```
View btn_v = view.findViewWithTag(aiPickedButton);
System.out.println("Button: " + btn_v);
btn = (Button) btn_v;
System.out.println("Button: " + btn);
```